# QTP, How to enhance Team Work?

Tags: automation, qtp

I Want to work on QTP with team, so there are different machines with different users use to make changes to same script, is there's any tool to enhance team working on QTP?

thanks 
Manaysah

Comment: What are you looking for? Source control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how we work:

We work locally in a SVN structure.

Every week we update the scripts uploaded in Quality Center with the local content.

We run the scripts from QC to obtain results.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about [TFS](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CFIQFjAD&url=http://www.slideshare.net/gueste6f731/working-as-a-team-with-team-foundation-server-2010&ei=wIHaUJ7YD8TAiwKUx4HYDg&usg=AFQjCNFMsQxaRuj9KczVKXgoKP56WmfObA&sig2=jUKDquc715vnxWAClGtuhA&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.cGE)?
Here is wiki [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Version Control System, then you can take any - TFS, SVN or whatever else. But it's better to take that one that is used by your development team - just to save effort on maintaining another server.

But if you are using QTP it might be useful for you to know that HP provides good integration with Quality Center (HP ALM QC). This integration helps a lot working together with the same scripts.